# Can C#(.NET 6) call managed/unmanaged C++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, .net-6.0

I'm attempting to call a c++ DLL(WinSDK: 10.0.18362.0, Platform Toolset: VS 2017 v141) from C#(the target framework is .NET 6.0) on ARM, and I compiled them for the ARM64 platform but got an exception when it was running:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL "Calculate.dll" or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.(0x8007007E)   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Sum(int a, int b)
```

**I'm sure I copied the DLL to the application directory and the program which was compiled for x64 platform worked.**

C# Console Application Code:

```
internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"Calculate.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern int Sum(int a, int b);
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input NumberA:");
                int numberA = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Input NumberB:");
                int numberB = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine($"The numberA is:{numberA}; the numberB is:{numberB}, the Sum is:{Sum(numberA, numberB)}");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ex:{ex}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Calculate.h code:

```
#pragma once

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Sum(int a, int b);

class Calculate
{
public:

};
```

Calculate.cpp code:

```
#include "Calculate.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    if (a - (int)a != 0 || b - (int)b != 0)
    {
        cout << "Please input a integrate" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

I want to know if C#(.NET 6.0) can call managed/unmanaged C++ DLL?
Are there any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: first try using absolute path to the DLL instead. Searching for paths in the current directory may be disabled due to security reasons so next try `.\Calculate.dll`

Comment: Which operating system are you running this on?

Comment: Windows 11 Pro 21H2 22000.613 @PMF

Comment: and then... "Unable to load DLL ".\Calculate.dll"" @phuclv

Comment: This somewhat still looks like it really is a problem of locating the DLL, since if the DLL had a wrong format you would typically get a BadImageFormatException instead.

Comment: I got a BadImageFormatException when I compiled it for ARM(not ARM64) platform and ran it. @PMF